# How can I sort a Finder search by size on OS 10.6.8?

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, search, sort

I'm using OSX 10.6.8, and when searching on finder, it doesn't let me sort files by size, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Snow Leopard system any more to test if I'm right, but can't you just enable the Size column then click on it in the header bar of the window?

Comment: Nope, that's the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

[Add columns to Spotlight search results](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/add-columns-to-spotlight-search-results.php)

Quote:

> Using Property List Editor
>
> If you are using Property List Editor, start by going to your user folder and then navigate to Library/Preferences. In the Preferences folder find the file named “com.apple.finder.plist.” Double-clicking on this file should open it up in Property List Editor. If not, just right-click on it and choose “Open With - Property List Editor.”
>
> Once the file is open, scroll down the list to “SearchViewSettings.” Click the disclosure triangle next to it, and then do the same for “ListViewSettings” and then “columns.” Now you should see a list of all the available columns. Click the triangle next to the column you want to add, i.e. size, and then check the box next to “visible.”

[image]

> Once you are done, save the file by pressing Command-S. Finally, you will need to restart the Finder for the changes to take effect. The easiest way to do this is top hold down the Control and Option keys, click on the Finder icon in the Dock and choose “Relaunch.”
>
> Now just press Command-F to bring up a search window and you should have your extra columns enabled.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the illustrative screenshot, I *do* know how to search files and sort results. I mentioned *OS 10.6.8* specifically because searching by file size and sorting results by file size are disabled by default, you can't choose them from any dropdown available. What OS do you have? Lion?

Comment: I use Lion. Does Snow Leopard allow sorting the search results at all? Can you click on any of the drop down menus?

Comment: Yes, you can sort by the available columns as in a regular finder window.  
Right clicking the column headers does nothing, but the same list is accesible through Command-J although Size, comments and label are greyed out and you can't select them.

Comment: I'm using Lion and wasn't seeing any sort options, plus my headings were not selectable. I fixed it by pressing `Command + J` and changing to `Arrange By = None` and `Sort By = Size`

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by going to Users/Library/Preferences.
2. In the Preferences folder, find the file named “com.apple.finder.plist.
3. Trash this file by highlighting it and hitting the "Command" and "Delete" keys.
4. Hit the "Command/Option/Escape" keys, and then relaunch the Finder in "Force Quit Applications".
5. All your greyed-out problems should now be eliminated.